# Which genetic optimization algorithm can output multiple solutions in python?

Tags: python, function, optimization, genetic-algorithm, scipy-optimize

I have a function i want to maximize, but it would probably take far too long to converge to a optimum, also I would assume there exists a lot of near optimas. Is there an genetic optimization algorithm in phyton I can use to generate mulitple optimal solutions after a specified time?

Comment: Have you considered plotting it to give you a hint of where the minima might be?

Comment: No not yet, it has 10 input parameters so that might be so much to plot.

Comment: See e.g. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/487459